# How to fix KeyError: 'DISPLAY' in python while using pyautogui library

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to make my computer click automatically by using PyAutoGUI Library
in Online IDE Repl.it showing `KeyError: 'DISPLAY'`, although I imported pyautogui packages correctly. How to fix this please ? help.

When I tried in a terminal, it worked fine and in Repl.it I imported pyautogui package correctly in requirment.text but still error is occurring

```
 import pyautogui
 import time

 i = 0
 while i<20:
     pyautogui.click(42, 756)
     time.sleep(1)
     i += 1
```

```
File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 161, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

Comment: PyAutoGUI is a library that interacts with the mouse and keyboard associated with a computer. Does a server have a mouse or keyboard? Well, no. If you think this will handle your mouse or keyboard then you are wrong. In conclusion, you can not.

Comment: You need potentially headless X server to do automation with this library. Repl.it does not provide one.